# How to add extra resources files in production in electron using electron-forge

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge, electron-react-boilerplate

I have a file that I need to make my application work.

I am able to use the file in development by specifying fixed path

```js
var path = process.cwd() + '/src/app/components/task/Scripts';
```

and the file name after that. But after packaging the app I want to move the file I need into the `extraResources` folder in the system from where I will be able to use it

```js
let path = pathPackage.join(process.resourcesPath, 'extraResources');
```

I am using electron-forge maker to produce a production build exe. However there is no `extraResources` folder created after installing the exe.

I am specifying it in the `package.json` file

```json
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      "./extraResources/**"
    ]
  }
```

Can someone provide a solution for this? I have tested all examples but none of them worked.

Comment: Did you find any fix for this ? I'm running into the same thing

Answer (score 12):

As it mentions in the [documention](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration) (actual options [documented here](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#extraresource)), you can add files using the extraResource option of the packagerConfig configuration.

> **extraResource
> extraResource: string | string[]**
>
> - One or more files to be copied directly into the app's
>   **Contents/Resources** directory for macOS target platforms, and the
>   **resources** directory for other target platforms. *The  resources
>   directory can be referenced in the packaged app via the
>   **process.resourcesPath** value.*

For example, in your `package.json` file:

```
 {
   "config": {
     "forge": {
       "packagerConfig": { 
         "extraResource": [
           "./src/extraResources/file.txt",
           "./src/extraResources/folder"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The files will be placed in the `process.resourcesPath` directory when running `npm run package`.

Comment: Thanks @WhatsMyPurpose. This was more difficult to figure out then it should be b/c the google results are seemingly out of date.

Comment: This worked, but only for the packaged app. `process.resourcesPath` resolved to something weird when running `electron-forge start`. I had to use __dirname, which points to the `.webpack/main` folder in both production and dev settings. I used `copy-webpack-plugin` to put files there.

Comment: will this command copy the node_modules folder into the resources folder? Second will the paths break if I have development paths?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397570/expected-app-structure-and-pathing-problems-after-build-of-electron-project-usin

Comment: Dude thanks! Have been stuck on this all day. If anyone is using forge.config.js instead of package.json add `packagerConfig: { asar: true, extraResource: ['./src/extraResources']}`